# how to fix this fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

It's my first post in here, so I hope a friendly soul wanna help me.

I got this problem with my fluid inside of my obstacle. I want to "flood" my pumpkin head from inside out, to force the "honey"-fluid to come out from the mouth or so..

you can find my project here:
[image]

It seems like though, that the obstacle has an "invisible" "fill" or "wall" inside of it...

[image]

I have already tried to adjust different things on my fluid simulator, but, nothing seems to work out for me. I'm new to blender, changed from maya, so maybe it's just a stupid mistake I have overlooked.

I hope you can help me :)

Kind Regards
A

Comment: Hi, welcome. This could depend on the mesh object, probably. Usually with fluid interactions many factors can give weird results. Check obstacle object mesh for usual things, like unapplied scale, normals, double geometry, etc. I suspect this would be hard to solve without having your file. If you wish so, you can share it on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link.

Comment: Hi m.ardito!
Thank you so much for your answer, I have postet the link for the project now! :) I maybe have an idea about the problem could be something with the mesh, after deleting faces and adding the solidifyer.. I don't know if that can cause some problems.. as you say, The problem is the mesh of the obstical. The fluid runs perfect out of the mesh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your file, and noticed the "obstacle" (which has unapplied scale, as the domain and fluid too) was really a high detail mesh... but had 2 "geometry creating" modifiers not applied:

- a solidify to give depth to your pumpkin shape
- a catmull clark subsurf (level 4!) to smooth it out

that gives over half million polygons...

(note I uploaded - valid - images but atm I they don't show up... I guess imgur.com has issues... I'll fix this later if still needed. edit: now they seem ok.)

[image]

in order to check the mesh as the simulation could see it, I initially applied the solidify modifier, and inspected the resulting shape with the 3d print toolbox tools ("check all") which gave a lot of issues, and you can easily see that your solidified shape has many badly topologized surfaces (due to the modifier).

[image]

It does not seem that bad, at first glance, but since you later add a c/c subsurf (level 4) to this, the bad surface just becomes more smooth and detailed, but if you disable the c/c subsurf modifier, it is easy to spot several part of the mesh that have that bad topology

[image]

this kind of (resulting) mesh issues can easily give bad fluid sim results, imho. I would try to

1. remove the subsurf
2. fix topology after applying solidify
3. test the fluid sim with this simplified and fixed mesh

and/or practice with a much simpler obstacle mesh (think of a basic cube with a simple square hole), to be sure the simulation is correctly working with that, and only then, replace the obstacle with something more complex (but with good topology).

Comment: Thank you so much dude! I went in to fix the small awkward faces and verticese (spells?), so the model was much simpler. Then I removed the top of the mesh, and made a "stock" or what it's called in english? from the buttom, and then added it to the top of the mesh, so the top was only one face instead of 400 million. 

Wasn't really thinking about it, but now I will make sure all my future models evoid being complex builded! what can you say.. you learn something new everyday :P 

Thanks again! 

Best regards